# Besides gaming, can Xbox Series X controller be used to navigate tvOS 14.5 as a replacement remote controller?

Tags: appletv, remote-control

The current betas of tvOS 14.5 [reportedly add support](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/04/07/apple-seeds-tvos-14-5-beta-7-to-developers/) for Xbox Series X controllers and PlayStation controllers for gaming.

Setting aside games, I would like to know if either of those controllers under 14.5 can work as replacement or substitute remote control for regular use of an Apple TV 4K. I mean waking the Apple TV device, navigating icons and menus, launching and switching and exiting apps, and so on.